# How can I create a custom url for users to share based off of their form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, webflow

I'm fairly new to programming but was wondering how I could attach a users first/last name after my domain to make a custom URL?

I have a form that asks for a users name, email, phone, and how many kids they need babysat.
Once they submit the form I want the success page to show a custom url: domain.com/firstLast and then theoretically they can share their link with other people for a possible discount.

I have the copy function working but I cannot seem to get the url to display. Please help!

```
<body>
<section>
<container>
<div>
<div .form-wrapper>
<form>
<div .slider>
  <div .slide>
    <div .form-content>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div .slide>
    <div .form-content>
      <input type="email" id="email">
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div .slide>
    <div .form-content>
      <input type="tel" id="phone">
      <input type="submit" id="contactMe">
    </div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
</form>
<div class="success-message">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="share-link" id="share-link">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Url</button>

<script>
slug = document.getElementById("name").value;
slug = slug.replace(/\s/g, '');
url = "https://babysittingmadeeasy.com/" + slug;
document.getElementById("share-link").value = url;
<script>
....
```

[image]

Comment: what's your back end?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Your closing script tag is not correct. It needs to be `</script>`. What you have are 2 opening script tags, though that might have just been a typo in your question.

Comment: @zeterain I just forgot to add it in the code above, It's right in Webflow!

Comment: @ThalindaBandara I honestly have no clue.

Comment: is your success page different than that with this form?

Comment: @PharsaThapa I have a div with my form, success, and error elements in it

Comment: when do you want this function to work ? on Any Event? what is myFunction() 's purpose?

Comment: @PharsaThapa once the form is submitted I want to display a custom url on the success page.
The myFunction just lets the user copy the url easily

Comment: You mentioned that your success page is inside same html, and you need to submit the form ( is it submitted to server )? i believe this is not a big issue, you might need to work around on HTML too. So, i advise you to edit the post and update with the html code, at least up to form tag and your javascript codes.

Comment: Great! I can see an update. Now, what event triggers to do the mentioned task?

Comment: @PharsaThapa the form submission, but with webflow I can't add an onsubmit function :/

Comment: did your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

On your form tag

```
 <form id="onboarding-form">
```

And your js

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById('onboarding-form').onsubmit = function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           slug = document.getElementById("name").value;
    
          slug = slug.replace(/\s/g, '');
          url = "https://babysittingmadeeasy.com/" + slug;
          document.getElementById("share-link").value =  url ;
     }
    <script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want it to appear when I click the form submit button not copy link.

Comment: I can't attach  "onsubmit" to the form without having to hand-code it

Comment: Do you have any id or unique class names for the form?

Comment: it's id is onboarding-form

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what. You are a life saver!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218334/discussion-between-pharsa-thapa-and-marisa).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your Javascript after your HTML:

```js
<input type="text" name="share-link" id="share-link">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Link</button>

<script>
slug = document.getElementById("name").value;
slug = slug.replace(/\s/g, '');
url = "https://babysittingmadeeasy.com/" + slug;
document.getElementById("share-link").value = url;
</script>
```

As your code is currently written, your Javascript will execute before the element `share-link` exists.

Comment: I tried that. I placed it at the end of page before the </body> tag and it still didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is some problems:

1. Where is html tag with id="name". I also add 1 input tag with this attribute for you.
2. Just replace the  region below the defined html tag. Or put it on function - make sure that the script run after element is created.

Done. There is my test and result:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="hidden" value="demoname"/>
<input type="text" name="share-link" id="share-link">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Link</button>


<script>
var slug = document.getElementById("name").value;
slug = slug.replace(/\s/g, '');
url = "https://babysittingmadeeasy.com/" + slug;
document.getElementById("share-link").value = url;
</script>
```

[screenshot of result with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSNRO.png)

Best Regards,

Comment: The HTML tag "name" is in the form.

Form
  <input id="name" ...>
  <input id="email" ...>
  <input id="phone" ...>
  <input id="numOfKids" ...>

  <input type="submit: ...>
</form>

<div>
<input type=text id="share-link">